# git rev-list hangs infinitely

Tags: git, ssh

If I do `git clone` - it works perfect.

But if after it I try to use `git pull` it hungs (sometimes work fine):

git client version: 2.6.3

git server version: 2.1.4

output:

`$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git pull
10:20:56.507549 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'pull'
10:20:56.508283 run-command.c:343       trace: run_command: 'fetch' '--update-head-ok'
10:20:56.508877 exec_cmd.c:128          trace: exec: 'git' 'fetch' '--update-head-ok'
10:20:56.511135 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'fetch' '--update-head-ok'
10:20:56.520316 run-command.c:343       trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@server' 'git-upload-pack '\''/vol/git/repos/repo.git'\'''
10:20:58.384437 run-command.c:343       trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet'`

Answer (score 1):

The situation might improve five years later with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), and the use of more buffered I/O where we used to call many small write(2)s.

See [commit a698d67](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a698d67b08f98ddac0e6df898fbfab5b4fbd36b1), [commit 6af3b00](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6af3b00abc3d2af69e6bdf4f8c0843d7e3bf9c88), [commit 24b75fa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/24b75faf0da7a025a192ab4c65cb1f1d6dc6b7f6) (12 Aug 2020) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d8488b9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8488b9e86f241ba313d04091449869fb15154d6), 24 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`upload-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a698d67b08f98ddac0e6df898fbfab5b4fbd36b1): use buffered I/O to talk to rev-list
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Chris Torek</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Johannes Sixt</sup>

> Like [f0bca72dc77](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f0bca72dc77f62d61fc355bd6fe6e32b194950b8) ("`send-pack`: use buffered I/O to talk to pack-objects", 2016-06-08, Git v2.10.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7e58b8166e6ac191739cf9001e73b2157f3aead5) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c589a73de4394ad125a4effac227b3aec856fa1)), significantly reduce the number of system calls and simplify the code for sending object IDs to rev-list by using stdio's buffering.
>
> Take care to handle errors immediately to get the correct error code, and to flush the buffer explicitly before closing the stream in order to catch any write errors for these last bytes.